# awk to print more than 2 decimal values with trailing zero

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

Below is my input file,

`input.txt`

```
17.0
17.12
17.123
17.1234
17.120
17.1230
17.12340
17.00
17.000
17.0000
```

And i want the out put as below

`output.txt`

```
17.120
17.1230
17.12340
17.000
17.0000
```

i.e. i need the values with more than 2 decimal points with trailing zero. i Have used the below `awk` but the output file contains 17.00 also. How to ignore this.

`awk '/^[0-9]+[.][0-9][1-9]*0/' input.txt`

Output of awk

```
17.120
17.1230
17.12340
17.00
17.000
17.0000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why you want to do this using `awk`, `grep` suffices. Also, if you know that your input only contains valid numbers matching anything in front of the dot is quite unnecessary.

```
$ grep '[.]...*0$' input.txt
17.120
17.1230
17.12340
17.000
17.0000

$ grep -P '[.][0-9]{2,}0$' input.txt
17.120
17.1230
17.12340
17.000
17.0000
```

To fix your pattern just add one more `[0-9]` class; matching "at least two" means matching exactly two (`[0-9][0-9]`) plus zero or more `[0-9]*`):

```
$ awk '/[.][0-9][0-9][0-9]*0$/' input.txt
17.120
17.1230
17.12340
17.000
17.0000
```

or use `+`:

```
$ awk '/[.][0-9][0-9]+0$/' input.txt
17.120
17.1230
17.12340
17.000
17.0000
```

Comment: Yeah, true, why using awk if grep alone suffices? Good approach.

Comment: @jaypal Too kind :-) </ot>

Answer (score 1):

Through sed,

```
$ sed -n '/^[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\+0$/p' file
17.120
17.1230
17.12340
17.000
17.0000
```

Through awk,

```
$ awk '/^[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]+0$/' file
17.120
17.1230
17.12340
17.000
17.0000
```

Comment: what is the use of +0$ at the end in awk?

Comment: no, `+` is related to preceeding `[0-9]`. That is `[0-9]+` matches one or more digits.Following `0` matches the digit 0 and it should be at the line end because of `$`

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of fields after the `.`:

```
$ awk -F. '/0$/ && (split($2,a,"")>2)' file
17.120
17.1230
17.12340
17.000
17.0000
```

- check if the line ends with `0`.
- count the number of digits after the dot with `split()`. If there are more than 2, the check is True.
- when both conditions are accomplished, the line will be printed.